# How to create remote desktop access application using java?

Tags: java, swing

I have two computer in different network.I want to control one system from another.Both system have windows 7 operating system.Do any one have any idea how to do it??
I don't want to use team viewer or any other application.

Comment: use TeamViewer, Luke!

Comment: I don't want to use team viewer..or any other application.I need programmatic method that's why i mentioned java...

Comment: I don't think Java has any capabilities to interact with a system like Windows even on the same computer. If you want to do it from scratch Java is not the best option.

Comment: Can you clarify in more detail why you believe that you need to do this programmatically in a custom Java program?

Comment: Why do you want to write your own stuff instead of using a tried and tested product? That's like saying _"I don't like Firefox, I want to write my own browser."_

Comment: Because i want to plug this functionality with one existing application developed by my co.And i need the idea how to do it i don't need solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC has been the most popular choice when it comes to remote desktop/computing. Check out this open source implementation called TightVNC, it even has a viewer application implemented in Java:

http://www.tightvnc.com/release-jviewer2.php

Answer (score -2):

You can install Teamviewer into both computer.

I don't think that have a relationship with java and swing.
I think that you should correct the tags.

Comment: He wanted to build application like teamviewer in java